# how to replace the character?

Tags: php

```
   $a="dir=desc&order=position&"
```

i want to replace `=` to `-`,  `&` to `-`.

i using the following code:

```
           $a = str_replace('&','-',$a);
            $a = str_replace('=','-',$a);
```

it now turns to `dir-desc-order-position-`. but i want to get `dir-desc-order-position`. namely, the last character replace with null `""`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`rtrim($a,"-")`](http://php.net/rtrim) to remove that character if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$a = "dir=desc&order=position&";    
//Now replace the character '='
$a = str_replace('=', '-', $a);
$result = str_replace('&', '-', $a);
echo rtrim($result,"-");
?>
```

More on `rtrim()` refer to @Niet the Dark Absol answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the last character with `substr($a, 0, -1);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **trim** function if know what character have to remove from string else find the length of your string and use **substr** function by checking that if how many character needs to be remove from the string end.

Answer (score 0):

Remove last character in your string

```
substr_replace($string ,"",-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = str_replace('&','-',$a,1);
```

This will replace `&` by `-` for only once.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php
  $a = "dir=desc&order=position&";
  $pattern = '/&/';
  $replace = '-';
  $b =preg_replace($pattern , $replace, $a );
  $c = preg_replace('/=/','-',$b);
  echo $c;
  ?>
```

Comment: for special char you can use preg_replace